# CefSharp using Flash

Tags: wpf, winforms, flash, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am trying to automatically enable Flash in a WPF application using CEF 73 and pepflashplayer32_32_0_0_223.dll.

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs["enable-system-flash"] = "1";
settings.CefCommandLineArgs["ppapi-flash-path"] = ./PathToDirectory/pepflashplayer32_32_0_0_223.dll";
settings.CefCommandLineArgs["ppapi-flash-version"] = "32.0.0.223";
settings.CefCommandLineArgs["plugin-policy"] = "allow";

 Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Everything seems to work fine, except when transitioning from one flash file to another, the "Click to allow Flash" screen shows for a split second then disappears. It seems like CEF knows to automatically allow Flash, but checks each time the flash element loads.

Does anyone have any idea how to stop this page from popping up or how I can troubleshoot this further?

Thanks!

Comment: CEF has it's own support forum at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php best to ask there

Comment: Yup, I posted there as well. Just curious if anyone here had any thoughts

Comment: If you cross post then please post a link

Comment: Sure, here's the post on magpcss.org: https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16940